# Redirect requests to another folder

Tags: apache2

I want to redirect all the requests that come to the folder 'test' to 'test1' using apache configurations. How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Could use mod_alias to make it happen:

```
Alias /path/to/test /path/to/test1
```

Put this into your config for the website (or the config for the virtual host). If you have overrides enabled for the directory, this could be put in the .htaccess file for the root of your website.